# react-hook-form, always return string type value

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using **react-hook-form**.
I'm trying implemnet shopping cart with this library, but getting struggle with
get number value.
the input tag which **name="count"** always return string value even set **type="number"** when use 
**getValues("count")**.

For the string values of **name="count"**,  my custom function **increment** doesn't work I expected.
when I clicked + button, it return with string added.

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as Styled from './style';
import { useForm, ErrorMessage} from 'react-hook-form';
import { ItemCountForm  } from 'src/models/item-count'; 
export const CountForm:FC<{
  partialData : Omit<ItemCountForm,'count'>
}> = ({
  partialData
}) => {

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors,getValues, setValue } = useForm<{count:number}>({
    defaultValues:{
      count: 1}
  });

  const onSubmit = async(data: {count: number}) => { 
    console.log('submitted');
    const formData: ItemCountForm = {
      id: partialData.id,
      name: partialData.name,
      count: data.count, 
      price: partialData.price * data.count
    }
    console.log(formData);

  }
  const count = getValues('count'); 
  const onIncrease = () => count < 999 && setValue('count',Number(count) + 1);
  const onDecrease = () => count > 1 && setValue('count',count - 1);
  return(
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input type="number" name="count"  ref={register({
          min:{
            value:1,
            message: "you need at least 1"
          },
          max: {
            value: 999,
            message: "you can have at most 999"
          }
        })}/>
        <ErrorMessage 
          errors={errors} 
          name={"count"} 
          as={<Styled.ErrorText/>}
        />
        <button onClick={onIncrease}>+</button>
        <button onClick={onDecrease}>-</button>
        <button type="submit">Add Cart</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `onChange` event on an input of type number will give you the string corresponding to the entered number. That is a browser behaviour. When you are trying to update the value you need to parse the value to an integer and then update

```
  const onIncrease = () => count < 999 && setValue('count',parseInt(count) + 1);
  const onDecrease = () => count > 1 && setValue('count',parseInt(count) - 1);
```

Comment: hmm... interesting.. so every number type value must be type cast to via parseInt in every  request before sending server??

Comment: Yes, because input always returns you a string value

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: sounds like a hassle if we usually pass register like this `{...register('age')}`

Answer (score 25):

Maybe some years late, but let's leave this for next devs solving this.

react-hook-form v 7 has a `valueAsNumber` key on the option object you can pass as second param of register:

```
{...register('age', {valueAsNumber: true})}
```

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

Comment: I'd expect passing an interface to useForm should suffice to keep the type of the object!

Comment: Thank you, `valueAsNumber` is a great solution. Until now I was using:

```{...methods.register("age", { setValueAs: value => parseInt(value, 10) })}```.