# React-hook-form doesn't set isDirty to false when back to initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

In the official [example for controlled inputs](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-controller-ts-forked-qgx79) , if you modify the value of an input and then change it back to its initial value, `isDirty` will be set to true but won't be set back to false and `dirtyField` will contain the touched field.

In an older [example with uncontrolled inputs](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-formstate-ht098), we don't have quite same  behaviour. In fact, if you modify the value of an input and then change it back to its initial value, `isDirty` will still be falsy but `dirtyFields` will not contain the touched field.

Shouldn't `isDirty` be set back to false when the form is back to its initial state and `dirtyFields` should be empty?

Is it the intended behaviour?

Does the Controllers break the formState?

Comment: We have the same problem in our current project at work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`isDirty` is based on the form input values against default values.

https://react-hook-form.com/api#formState

> Make sure to provide all inputs' defaultValues at the useForm, so hook
> form can have a single source of truth to compare whether the form is
> dirty.

Here is an example with uncontrolled inputs:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-kapitsa-7m6o0?file=/src/App.tsx

example with controlled inputs:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-framework-op8jy?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 10):

Two years late, but adding to what Bill answered and if anyone has a similar issue (like I did). Not only does it need default values on the useForm, there can't be additional properties on the default values object that aren't on the form. The issue I had was that my form took a merge of the default values (for a new entry) and the data object (for editing an existing entry). So if you had something like this

```
const person = {id: 123, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Smith"};
```

and your form was used for editing and creating, the component could have a optional prop for "person" and useForm is setup like this

```
const formMethod = useForm({
  defaultValues: person || {firstName: "", lastName: ""},
});
```

I didn't add "id" to the form, because it wasn't ever going to be edited and you don't have an id for create, and the value was available for the update method. Maybe that's an anti-pattern, but it's what was done.

When the form is first rendered, isDirty will be false. When you change a value, isDirty will be true. When you change back to the original value, isDirty remains true, because ALL of the default values don't match the form input values and never will in this instance.

This is a simplistic example where the id could be added to the form as a hidden input or registered or something, but for a real solution, there could be lots of other fields that are coming down the api that aren't editable and shouldn't (or couldn't) be part of the form. Takeaway is this - make sure that your editing model matches your default values model. I used this to merge the objects, remove nulls, patch in missing props and remove props that weren't on the default. "mergeWith" and "pick" are lodash methods.

```
function mergeFormData(defaults: Object, data?: Object, removeExtras?: boolean) {
    if (!data) return defaults;

    // This should merge everything on data, and take
    // defaults where applicable.
    // It's only shallow merge, and it uses the "data" if it isn't null or undefined.
    // ?? should do it, so it will allow "" and 0 to be kept on the data object
    // Use removeExtras to take out props from the data object
    // that aren't on the default object

    return mergeWith({},
        removeExtras ? pick(data, Object.keys(defaults)) : data,
        defaults,
        (a, b) => {return a ?? b;});
}
```

And usage (in my case) for add/edit.

```
const formContext = useForm<AddressFormData>({
    defaultValues: mergeFormData(defaultAddress, address, true),
    resolver: yupResolver(addressSchema),
    mode: 'onBlur'
});
```

Comment: Well said. In my code i was not resetting the value and wanted the isDirty to be false after submitting the form data. Later i figured out that the value should reset after the form submission with what ever the default value or the object sent from the api.

Was really stuck in this for more than 2hrs hoping to help anyone with the similar kind of error.

Comment: Well said. And to add on, numbers will get converted to strings in the inputs so it helps if your default values are strings https://stackoverflow.com/a/61782474/5570385

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to subscribe to isDirty field from useForm then it will work.

`const { handleSubmit, control, formState: { isDirty }, } = useForm({ defaultValues: baseRecord, });`